# Modify the exception

Tags: wcf

I have 2 WCF services and a client which calls the method of 1st WCF service, and that method consequently calls the method of 2nd WCF service. The method of 2nd WCF service rises a generic fault exception, I need that this exception will be normally 'delivered' to my client through the 1st service. The 1st WCF service normally gets that generic exception with some `Action` "http://SomeNamespace" in exception message body. When the 1st service rethrow this exception to client, the client gets simple `FaultException` instead of `FaultException`1`. I think the problem is in`Action` which contains a namespace which is not acceptable for the client, and that's why the client is not able to get generic exception. There is a WCF Exception Shielding in 1st WCF service. Below are the configuration code and the handler code.
Please help me and advise the best way to change the action of exception that the client will be able to get it normally.

Here is the config:

```
<exceptionHandling>
      <exceptionPolicies>
        <add name="WCF Exception Shielding">
          <exceptionTypes>
            <add type="System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Sample.SomeFaultContract, Sample, PublicKeyToken=769e6b46280078d4]], System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException" name="SomeFaultContract">
                <exceptionHandlers>
                  <add faultContractType="Sample.SomeFaultContract, Sample, PublicKeyToken=769e6b46280078d4"
                    type="Helper.ServiceFaultContractHandler, Logger, PublicKeyToken=769e6b46280078d4"
                    name="Fault Contract Exception Handler" />
                </exceptionHandlers>
            </add>
          </exceptionTypes>
        </add>
  </exceptionHandling>
```

And the handler part is:

```
public class ServiceFaultContractHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
   public ServiceFaultContractHandler(NameValueCollection ignore) { }

   public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid correlationID)
   {


   }        
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Aram

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the details of the exception, you should set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults property to true in the service behavior.
Below is a sample:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WCFServicesName">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is already set in the configurations. The client's contract has his own namespace and it gets the exception with different namespace and doesn't recognize that exception. For testing purpose I have changed the client's namespace with the namespace which is in excpetion's Action and it worked smoothly. But unfortunately I can't change any namespace, only can somehow handle the exception in 1st WCF service and send the it to client with right namespace.